# Move a rotating object in a HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an HTML canvas. Inside it I've drawn a hexagon. The hexagon rotates in place.
Well now I want this rotating hexagon to move along a set path. I want to be able to track it's location.

Normally when you want to move an object you say: (object.x+howmuchtomove) and it will simply
move by that much, and you can track it's whereabouts by just adding object.x+howmuchtomove to get the x coord.

Well in this case I'm using translate and rotate to give it the rotating effect. So adding +2 to it's x location simply makes it rotate in a bigger circle.

Here is what I've got, thanks!

```
   retObject.draw = function() {    
        // Wipe the canvas      
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";         
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Draw rotating shape
        ctx.save(); // Don't rotate everything
        ctx.strokeStyle="red"; // Set Color     
        ctx.translate(356.5, 700); // Center pivot inside hexagon
        ctx.rotate(rotValue*(Math.PI/180)); // Rotate           
        ctx.translate(-356.5, -700); // Un-Translate    
            for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();        
                ctx.moveTo(300, 700); 
                ctx.lineTo(330, 650);
                ctx.lineTo(383, 650);
                ctx.lineTo(413, 700);
                ctx.lineTo(383, 750);
                ctx.lineTo(330, 750);
                ctx.lineTo(300, 700);
                ctx.stroke(); // Draw Hexagon
            }
        ctx.restore(); // Get back normal
    }
```

Note that draw() is inside of a loop so that it gets called every frame.

So, for simplicity sake, say I just want this rotating hexagon to drop straight down.
Basically I'm wanting to add +1 to it's y coordinate every frame.

Comment: You are moving the element along as expected, but you are not moving the centre of rotation along with the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out and I feel stupid.

You simply add the desired move amount to the first translate ONLY.

**So:**

```
ctx.translate(356.5, 700);
```

**Becomes:**

```
ctx.translate(356.5, 700+moveAmount);
```

That will make it move straight down by "moveAmount" per frame.

 Maybe this will help someone lol